Should I include payslips and letter from my previous employer in my UK Standard Visitor visa application?
I am a permanent resident in Canada and working in Canada. I have worked for my current employer for over a year. Before that, I used to work for a different employer.
In the application form for Standard Visitor visa, I can only enter my current employer information. As for the supporting documents, should I only provide proofs of employment (payslips, employment letter) that are related with my current employment, or should I also include the ones that are from my previous employment as well?
Thanks in advance.

Just the current one, else they would ask for more. Past is past (and the relevancy should just be on capital)

If you had just changed jobs then it would make sense to provide the payslips of the previous employer (so all credits on the bank statements you provide are justified), but there’s no need to go back over a year (even a year seems a stretch, 3 to 6 months are usually enough if your situation is stable).

No.
From the UK’s Guide to supporting documents:


Documents you should not use as evidence

Some types of documents are less useful as evidence in visit applications. These include:

bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of application


